# A simple help needed about creating table

Tags: sql-server

I am totally new in SQL and SQL Server without any prior IT knowledge. However I try to learn SQL Server just from the love of it. My question is very simple. I am having problem creating table using sql code. I want to create a table named `new_table` from another table `old_table`. my code is:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table
AS (SELECT * FROM old_table)
```

but it is giving following error: `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2 Incorrect syntax near '('.`

I have done many things but could not figure out what is the problem. Can any one please guide me what is the problem?

Comment: SQL Server does not support the ANSI SQL standard for this type of operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * INTO new_table 
FROM SourceTable
```

`new_table`  must not already exist.

[Ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx).

In response to your comment:

```
SELECT * INTO dbo.new_table 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT col1 FROM old_table) tmptable
```

Comment: Thank you :) however I want to bring only a single column and then group by it. With my code I thought I would write the code like this: CREATE TABLE new_table
as (select new_table.col1 from old_table
group by new_table.col1). I cant figure it out how can I group by using your method. But thanks that I can now atleast know how to create a table :)

Comment: yes :) but I thought rather creating a separate question / thread, I ask it in here. And with best of my knowledge it is somewhat similar. :)

Comment: So now you've unaccepted my answer to your question and accepted one which answers neither question you have just asked. sigh!

Comment: sorry I still do not understand this forum. Can I not accept/multiple answers? hmmm... I see that I can not select multiple answers. Sorry :S This is only my second post in stackoverflow. Now I selected your answer which perfectly answer my question :) sorry for the inconvenience...

Answer (score 1):

The `CREATE TABLE new_table AS` is not valid in SQL Server. (That answers the question you asked, about what the problem is.)

Equivalent functionality is available in Microsoft SQL Server (T-SQL), but it uses T-SQL syntax which is different:

```
SELECT * INTO new_table FROM old_table
```

That will allow you to create new table contains all of the columns and rows from an existing table.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029(v=sql.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Include Top 0 if you just need the table structure(without data)

```
SELECT TOP 0 * INTO new_table FROM old_table
```